# How do I enable a Data Factory Git repository when connecting to GitHub?

Tags: github, azure-data-factory

I have migrated from Azure DevOps to GitHub recently and am trying to update the Azure Data Factory source control connection to GitHub.

My Infrastructure as code looks like:

```
var repoConfig = {
  repoConfiguration: {
    type: 'FactoryGitHubConfiguration'
    accountName: '<org>'
    repositoryName: '<repo name>'
    collaborationBranch: 'develop'
    rootFolder: '<file path>'
  }
}

var useRepo = (toLower(env) == 'dev01') ? repoConfig : {}

resource ADF 'Microsoft.DataFactory/factories@2018-06-01' = {
  name: adfName
  location: location
  properties: useRepo
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
  tags: appTags
}
```

When opening up the Data Factory Studio I am prompted to log in to GitHub
[image]

After trying to sign in I get an error message saying:

[image]

I noticed in the Applications tab that AzureDataFactory was in a pending state. I had an organization admin approve it and now I have a green check mark

[image]

After this, I can go back to Data Factory Studio > Manage > Git configuration and see the proper set up:

[image]

However, on the Dashboard it keeps prompting to log in to GitHub and say I am not connected. I also am unable to chose a different branch:

[image]

Is there a step that I am missing or something misconfigured?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I faced the same issue with access Token. I followed the below approach.

- Open GitHub -> Developer settings ->Personal access token -> generate new and provide required access to repositories

[image]

Reconnect back GitHub with ADF

[image]

Now you can check GitHub connected.

[image]

For more information refer this [GitHub link](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token)